# Passing service instance ID into guest executable at runtime

Tags: azure-service-fabric

Is it possible to pass service instance ID (int value) into guest executable at runtime? I have looked at `<ExeHost><Arguments>`, but it's only good for static data that has to be provided up front.

Comment: What do you plan to use it for? It's available (see my answer on that) but whether it's actually useful depends on what you plan to do with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's available in an environment variable. See here for a complete list of environment variables available to services: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-manage-multiple-environment-app-configuration

Note that the one you're asking for, **Fabric_ServicePackageInstanceId** is generally only meant for internal consumption, and it identifies the entire service package. That means if you have multiple code packages (executables) in your service package, they will all get the same ID.

Answer (score 2):

The environment variable provides the *service package instance ID* which is not the same as the instance/replica ID. Generally speaking, SF's environment variables can provide the same information available using `FabricRuntime`, i.e. the node context and the code package activation context. In native SF services, the instance ID is provided at run-time by the Fabric (in the `ServiceContext` class), as a single process can host multiple partitions and instances/replicas.

In a guest executable, which does not use SF APIs, the only option AFAIK is to query the Fabric for this information in a separate executable, run it as the `SetupEntryPoint` (which runs every time before the guest executable) and write the information to a file.

For example (compile the code into `GetFabricData.exe` and add it to the code package):

```cs
private static async Task MainAsync(string[] args)
{
    var serviceTypeName = args.FirstOrDefault();
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(serviceTypeName)) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(serviceTypeName));

    using (var client = new FabricClient())
    {
        var activationContext = FabricRuntime.GetActivationContext();
        var nodeContext = FabricRuntime.GetNodeContext();
        var nodeName = nodeContext.NodeName;
        var applicationName = new Uri(activationContext.ApplicationName);

        var replicas = await client.QueryManager.GetDeployedReplicaListAsync(nodeName, applicationName);
        // usually taking the first may not be correct
        // but in a guest executable it's unlikely there would be multiple partitions/instances
        var instance = replicas.OfType<DeployedStatelessServiceInstance>()
            .FirstOrDefault(c => c.ServiceTypeName == serviceTypeName);

        if (instance == null)
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException($"Unable to find a service instance for {serviceTypeName}");
        }

        File.WriteAllText("FabricData", instance.InstanceId.ToString());
    }
}
```

And in the service manifest:

```xml
<SetupEntryPoint>
  <ExeHost>
    <Program>GetFabricData.exe</Program>
    <Arguments>Guest1Type</Arguments>
  </ExeHost>
</SetupEntryPoint>
```

Then, the guest executable can simply read the `FabricData` file.

Comment: in my case guest executable is not SF aware, so querying is not an option. What Vaclav said works the best.

Comment: that's a neat idea. Sort of bootstrapper (or from the Cloud Services days "startup task").

Comment: in case of multiple instances of a guest executable, is it possible to find out what instance ID to use from the list of replicas?

Comment: Could also partition the service and have an instance on each partition. But that's an extreme. Thanks a lot for your answers.